# equivalent of bitfield for C structure in python

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, struct, bit-fields

I am having a bitfield structure in C and i want to implement the same in python.
With the structure i am having in C i am able to get 2 byte of data through it..and i write this data in a file in binary format..
The same thing i want to implement with python but i am not able to get any fruitful solution till now..
The structure for the C is as follows:

```
struct test { 
        unsigned int x : 5; 
        unsigned int y: 3; 
        unsigned int z : 8; 
   };
```

Please help me with the above mentioned issue..
Thanks in Advance

To be more precise i am having a structure as below which i am writing in a binary file

```
typedef struct abc{
unsigned int year       :12; 
unsigned int Month      :4;

unsigned int Date       :5;
unsigned int Hour       :5;
unsigned int Min        :6;

unsigned int Sec        :6;
unsigned int w          :1;
unsigned int x          :1; 
unsigned int y          :8;

unsigned int z          :8;

unsigned int q          :8;
}abc ;
```

i am filling the structure as follows:

```
abc.year=2020
abc.Month=2
abc.Date=31
abc.Hour=12
abc.Min=45
abc.Sec=25
abc.w=0
abc.x=1
abc.y=145
abc.z=100
abc.q=120
```

The output i am getting in the output file is as follows:
E4 27 9F B5 99 91 64 78

The same thing i need to do with python..so please help me with this

Comment: https://jdb.github.io/bitfield.html

Comment: @KenKinder: That's something different.

Comment: @KenKinder. There is a struct module. It does not apply here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/142812

Comment: @RobertHarvey i am getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bitfield' and when i run pip3 install bitfield then i am getting ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement bitfiled (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for bitfiled

Comment: The Github is here: https://github.com/Notgnoshi/Bitfield

Comment: Also, note that your error message claims you misspelled "bitfield".

Comment: @RobertHarvey not able to install this module from github

Comment: Oh, well.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/142812 then.