# Encoding a integer in python for a custom architecture

Tags: python, encoding, cpu

I am writing an assembler for a custom architecture in Python, and am getting stuck on the encoding step. I need to set bits 0-16, 16-32, and 32-64 to their own integer values, however, have difficulty doing this due to my lack of knowledge and me not knowing how to check if a value has been encoded correctly

My old encoding function was

```
def _encode_bits(self, i, offset: int, length: int, value: int) -> None:
        assert(offset >= 0)
        assert(length >= 0)
        assert(offset + length < 65)
        assert(value >= 0)
        assert(value < 2 ** length)

        mask = ((1 << length) - 1) << offset
        encoding = self.instr_data[i]
        encoding &= ~mask
        encoding |= value << offset

        self.instr_data[i] = encoding
```

However, as mentioned before, I currently do not know if there is a way to verify this function, or if there is a better method

Comment: Potentially related: [Does Python have a bitfield type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/142812/11082165)